# Entry form replacing rather than appending data to a matrix field

Tags: matrix, entry-form

I have this in my entry form:

```
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('entryId', entry.id) }}
        {{ hiddenInput('fields[questions][sortOrder][]', 'new:1') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', section.id) }}
        {% namespace "fields[questions][blocks][new:1]" %}
        {{ hiddenInput('type', 'question') }}
        <div>
            <label for="question">Question</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="fields[question]"
                id="question"
                value="…"
            >
        </div>
        {% endnamespace %}
```

This is working fine for saving a new matrix block, but if I then want to resubmit and save more blocks, it's not creating new blocks, but overwriting the data of the existing one.

What do I need to change for it to save new blocks as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old blocks are likely being discarded due to the way Craft handles “delta saves” for complex fields like Matrix.

[This section](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-fields.html#block-order) of the Matrix field documentation should help you persist existing blocks!

```
{# Output existing block IDs to keep them around: #}
{% for blockId in entry.questions.anyStatus().ids() %}
  {{ hiddenInput('fields[questions][sortOrder][]', blockId) }}
{% endfor %}

{# Tell Craft about the new block: #}
{{ hiddenInput('fields[questions][sortOrder][]', 'new:1') }}

{# Output your fields, as you are now! #}
```

You do *not* need to POST all the existing fields back to persist the blocks—as long as their IDs are in the `sortOrder` array, Craft will leave them as-is!

> You can also insert the block at the beginning by placing the `new:1` input *before* the existing block IDs.